# Dismiss dialog when gps provider enabled

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog, android-location

I'm checking the gps provider status and if it's disable I show an AlertDialog. I want to automatically dismiss this AlertDialog when gps provider status change to enabled.

I made check in `onResume()` and everything is good except if the user change the location settings by the quick settings drop down - then `onResume()` is not called.

`onWindowFocusChanged()` is not being called either.

Answer (score 0):

try this code...

```
public class getLocation implements
    LocationListener {

 @Override
public void onCreate() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate();


}


@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {


}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

 if(provider.equalsIgnoreCase("gps"))
    {
        dialog.dismiss();
    }

}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

}
```

Hope this Code Helps You...